# Facebook Post with Photo/Video

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have a website with Facebook capabilities (Sending personal messages, posting to wall). I use both the PHP and JavaScript Facebook SDKs. For posting to users walls/FanPages I use the following JavaScript SDK `feed` dialog:

```
function generalPost(producerID, producerName, fanPageID)
{ 
   var obj =
   {
      method: 'feed',
      link: '<?php echo SEAT_NEAR_ME; ?>?producerID='+ producerID,
      type: 'video',
      picture: 'https://<?php echo DOMAIN; ?>/DATA/producersPic/<?php echo $_SESSION["IMG"];?>',
      from: fanPageID,
      to: fanPageID, //fan page ID
      show_error: true,
      name: producerName,
      caption:'    ',
      description: '                     '
   };

      FB.ui(obj, function(response){
               if (response && response.post_id) 
               {
                   //post success
               } 
               else 
               {
                   //alert('Post was not published.');
               }
           }); 
}
```

This produces the following dialog: (I've blurred the personal information)

[image: Feed dialog]

I want to add 'Photo / Video' upload capability for my dialog, just as (or similar to) to the one on facebook:

[image: Post with video]

I've googled about it and checked the Facebook docs and only found this:

[Photo batch uploads](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/)

I have two question:

1. Is this what I need or is there any better way to write the photo/video dialog ?
2. From the [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/) I've found, What does this means: `$my_url = "YOUR_POST_LOGIN_URL"`
   What is `POST_LOGIN_URL` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to post photos / videos, then you will have to post the actual files to facebook using cURL or another method. This [Blog Post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/) details the process for uploading photos. You won't be able to use the JavaScript Feed Dialog to upload photos / videos.

The `POST_LOGIN_URL` is where you want the user to go after they have logged in.

Comment: But the user is already logged in to Facebook when he is in my website page that allows him to post (I use Facebook Login). So what do I need to provide as the `POST_LOGIN_URL` ?

Comment: The `POST_LOGIN_URL` is where you want non-logged in users to go once they've logged in. Read up on the documentation - this is all covered by Facebook.

Comment: Or if they are already logged in, they will be redirected to the `POST_LOGIN_URL` after they get the necessary TOKEN. Thanks for note.